# What should be the value of the tos_acceptance[date] parameter when requesting Stripe Connect to create a managed account?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

Is the `tos_acceptance.date` parameter in Unix time? The documentation only says it should be a date.

From the looks of its value here (https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object) and from the error message I receive when I try to make a call to Stripe assuming that the date is in Unix time, I get an error that says:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "ToS acceptance date is not valid. Dates are expected to be integers, measured in seconds, not in the future, and after 2009.",
    "param": "tos_acceptance[date]"
  }
}
```

But there is no documentation that tells us how this date value is supposed to be arrived at.

Comment: all dates in stripe are unix timestamps

Comment: Thanks. @MatthewArkin. The value I supply also is a unix timestamp. The value a few minutes ago was 1455791826. It still gives me the same error as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: That is equal to 02/18/2016 @ 10:37am (UTC) which is about 4 hours in the future

Comment: @MatthewArkin Ah, catch, the catch. It's UTC! Eureka! They should have said so, and I should have guessed. I was computing it based on my local time. How narcissistic. :-)

Answer (score 3):

for anyone else that google this error

this is what i used

`var moment = require('moment');
var time = moment.utc().valueOf();
tos_acceptance.date = Math.floor(time / 1000);`

"integers, measured in seconds"
SECONDS, not milliseconds.
so not Date.now() which => the date in milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using moment library, we can simply calculate unix timestamp as:

```
tos_acceptance.date = Math.floor(Date.now()/ 1000)
```